# Is there a jQuery-like library written in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, xml

I love jQuery. I am probably going to have some XML parsing and manipulation using C#. It would be a piece of cake doing it in jQuery.

Is there a C# library that implements jQuery's functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), for what you want to do.

Comment: Except not all HTML is XML.

Comment: @pilotbob: Nobody said anything about HTML.

Comment: Right sorry, I saw jQuery and assumed my mind then say they wanted to parse html server side. (Since that is what I was looking for do when I can across this.)

Answer (score 8):

Old question but new answer. I've recently released version 1.1 of [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery), a jQuery port  for .NET 4 written in C# that I've been working on for about a year. Also on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery) as "CsQuery"

The current release implements all CSS2 & CSS3 selectors, all jQuery extensions, and all jQuery DOM manipulation methods. It's got extensive test coverage including all the tests from jQuery and sizzle (the jQuery CSS selection engine). I've also included some performance tests for direct comparisons with Fizzler; for the most part CsQuery dramatically outperforms it. The exception is actually loading the HTML in the first place where Fizzler is faster; I assume this is because fizzler doesn't build an index. You get that time back after your first selection, though.

There's documentation on the github site, but at a basic level it works like this:

Create from a string of HTML

```
CQ dom = CQ.Create(htmlString);
```

Load synchronously from the web

```
CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.jquery.com");
```

Load asynchronously (non-blocking)

```
CQ.CreateFromUrlAsync("http://www.jquery.com", responseSuccess => {
    Dom = response.Dom;        
}, responseFail => {
    ..
});
```

Run selectors & do jQuery stuff

```
var childSpans = dom["div > span"];
childSpans.AddClass("myclass");
```

the `CQ` object is like thejQuery object. The property indexer used above is the default method (like `$(...)`.

Output:

```
string html = dom.Render();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) is probably what you are looking for.